# Missing Users tab in CMS

Tags: users, admin

I seem to be missing the users panel in the CMS. Any idea where it could have gone? For adding new users, groups etc.

[image]

Am a bit confused, and new to craft. So, sorry if this is painfully obvious.

Thank-you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, you're using the `Personal` version of Craft, which only allows for one user, which is why you won't see a Users section in the sidebar or the Settings screen. If you upgrade your install to `Client` or `Pro` you'll see those Users sections appear

Also worth a note, in Craft 3 and the latest version of Craft 2, the editions have been renamed to `Solo` and `Pro`. `Solo` is just like `Personal`: only one user allowed, whereas `Pro` allows for more than one user.

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense. Thank-you!

Comment: No worries. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in with a Super Admin account or a different account?

Depending on your user/group permissions you may or may not have access to the Users section.

Log in as a Super Admin and check the permissions for the group/account that you had originally logged in as.

Comment: This answer _can_ also be true, however we can see from the screenshot that the OP is using Craft Personal, which limits the instance to 1 account as per Jalen's answer.

Comment: Aha yes I missed that!